# How to change image and change class name using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to change image and change class name using javascript ?

I try with my code but not work, What is wrong?

this code will

1. change class name from `.black` to `.red`
2. change element from

   `<div id="abcd" style=" border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px;">
       <img src="https://0.s3.envato.com/files/122605825/thumb.png"/>
   </div>`

to

```
<div id="abcd" style=" border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px;">
    <img src="https://0.s3.envato.com/files/118176445/thumbnail.png"/>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/28L8yk79/1/

javascript code

```
<script>
function test_fn() {           
    $('#12345-6).html('<div id="abcd" style=" border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px;"><img src="https://0.s3.envato.com/files/118176445/thumbnail.png"/></div>').addClass('red').removeClass('black');    
}
</script>
```

Please solve me by using like my code. thank you

Comment: You haven't closed the selector, missing `'`.

Comment: @robert werder check my answer

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<script>
function test_fn() {    
    $('#12345-6')
          .removeClass('black')
          .addClass('red')
          .find('#abcd img')
               .attr('src', 'https://0.s3.envato.com/files/118176445/thumbnail.png');
}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/28L8yk79/15/

Answer (score 2):

your missing an ' in the selector :

```
<script>
function test_fn() {           
    $('#12345-6').html('<div id="abcd" style=" border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px;"><img src="https://0.s3.envato.com/files/118176445/thumbnail.png"/></div>').addClass('red').removeClass('black');    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

see updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/28L8yk79/2/). missing an ' in the selector

```
function test_fn() {           
     $('#12345-6').html('<div id="abcd" style=" border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px;"><img src="https://0.s3.envato.com/files/118176445/thumbnail.png"/></div>').addClass('red').removeClass('black');    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Beamer said, I would use something more practical. You don't need to inject html again, just modified your one.

```
function test_fn() {           
var imageUrl = 'https://0.s3.envato.com/files/118176445/thumbnail.png'
$('#12345-6').addClass('red').removeClass('black').find('img:first').attr('src', imageUrl);
```

}